# Pivoting Columns into Rows and Rows into Columns at the same time. (SSMS)

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have the following table...let's call it Table1

```
 TERM           PERIOD  Average     StandardDeviation   Minimum
+ 1 Period      2012Q3  0.00417     0.00722             0
+ 120 Periods   2012Q3  0.02951     0.0014              0.028615
+ 20 Periods    2012Q3  0.009898    0.0037              0.007612
+ 40 Periods    2012Q3  0.018255    0.00262             0.016565
+ 1 Period      2012Q4  0.005       0.007               0
+ 120 Periods   2012Q4  0.026       0.001               0.03
+ 20 Periods    2012Q4  0.007       0.003               0.0042
+ 40 Periods    2012Q4  0.018       0.002               0.0165
```

Is there a way to code this so I can have a table that looks like so:

```
TERM           PATHS              2012Q3    2012Q4
+ 1 Period     Average            0.00417   0.005
+ 1 Period     StandardDeviation  0.00722   0.007
+ 1 Period     Minimum            0         0
```

...and so on for each TERM ( + 120 Periods, + 40 Periods, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To produce this result, you will want to use both the [`UNPIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and the [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function.  The `UNPIVOT` takes the columns `Average`, `StandardDeviation` and `Minimum` and converts them into multiple rows. Once you have the rows, then you can apply the `PIVOT` to the `Period` values.  Your code will be similar to this:

```
select term, paths,[2012Q3], [2012Q4]
from
(
  select term, period, paths, value
  from
  (
    select term, period, Average, StandardDeviation, Minimum
    from table1
  ) s
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for paths in (Average, StandardDeviation, Minimum)
  ) unpiv
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for period in ([2012Q3], [2012Q4])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/878e3/4).

This can also be done using a `UNION ALL` to unpivot the data and an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression to pivot:

```
select term,
  paths,
  max(case when period = '2012Q3' then value end) [2012Q3],
  max(case when period = '2012Q4' then value end) [2012Q4]
from
(
  select term, period, 'Average' Paths, average value
  from Table1
  union all
  select term, period, 'StandardDeviation' Paths, StandardDeviation
  from Table1
  union all
  select term, period, 'Minimum' Paths, Minimum
  from Table1
) src
group by term,  paths
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6c634/5).

The above versions work great if you have a known number of `period` values. If you don't then you will want to use dynamic sql to generate the result:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(PERIOD) 
                    from Table1
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query 
    = 'select term, paths, '+@cols+'
       from
       (
         select term, period, paths, value
         from
         (
           select term, period, Average, StandardDeviation, Minimum
           from table1
         ) s
         unpivot
         (
           value
           for paths in (Average, StandardDeviation, Minimum)
         ) unpiv
       ) p
       pivot
       (
          max(value)
          for period in('+@cols+')
       ) piv'

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6c634/7).

All of the versions produce the same result.

Comment: Yeah I always try to use Dynamic SQL when I have a whole ton of columns

Answer (score 0):

I approach this as an aggregation and a join . . .

```
select term, paths,
       MIN(case when period = '2012Q3'
                then (case when which = 'Average' then t.average
                           when which = 'StandardDeviation' then t.StandardDeviation
                           when which = 'Minimum' then t.Minimum
                      end)
            end) as "2012Q3",
       MIN(case when period = '2012Q4' 
                then (case when which = 'Average' then t.average
                           when which = 'StandardDeviation' then t.StandardDeviation
                           when which = 'Minimum' then t.Minimum
                      end)
            end) as "2012Q4"
from Table1 t cross join
     (select 'Average' as paths union all
      select 'StandardDeviation' union all
      select 'Minimum'
     ) const
group by term, paths
```